# Restricted partitions with square terms only

Tags: generating-functions, partitions

Let $P(N,M,n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ such that each term is $\le N$ and there are at most $M$ terms. So we know the generating function for $P(N,M,n)$ is $ \frac{(q)_{N+M}}{(q)_M (q)_{N}}$. Let $P_{sq}(n)$ be the partitions of $n$ such that all terms are perfect squares. The generating function for this would be $\prod \limits_{k \ge 1} 1/(1-q^{k^2})$. One can easily obtain a generating function for $P_{sq} (N^{2},n)$ where each term of the partition is $\le N^2$ by restricting $k$ from $1$ to $N$ in the generating function above.

So my question is that can we find a generating function for $P_{sq} (N^2,M,n)$? If yes, please tell me how.

Comment: It's the coefficient of $z^M$ in $$\prod_{k=0}^N (1-q^{k^2} z)^{-1}.$$

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Will not the coefficient involve powers of $q$?

Comment: It will be a function (power series) in $q$ that you look for.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev As far as I can understand, you are saying that the generating function that I am looking for is the power series that you described here but unfortunately, when I wrote down the series, I figured that it doesn't seem to be the case. Can you tell me how did you arrive at this result? Probably make it into a full answer?

Comment: I've posted this as an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shown that $\frac{(q)_{N+M}}{(q)_N(q)_M}$ is the coefficient of $z^M$ in
$$\prod_{k=0}^N (1-q^kz)^{-1}.$$
In other words,
$$P(N,M,n) = [q^n z^M]\ \prod_{k=0}^N (1-q^kz)^{-1}.$$
Here $z$ in each term $(1-q^kz)^{-1} = 1+q^kz + q^{2k}z^2 + \dots$ accounts for how many parts equal $k$ are present in the restricted partition. This includes the case of $k=0$, which accounts for parts equal 0 to allow us have less than $M$ nonzero parts (if $k=0$ is excluded from the product, the coefficient of $q^nz^M$ would give the number of restricted partitions with exactly $M$ nonzero parts).

By similar arguments, the number of restricted partitions into squares is
$$P_{sq}(N^2,M,n) = [q^n z^M]\ \prod_{k=0}^N (1-q^{k^2}z)^{-1}.$$
However, I doubt that there exists a simple expression for the generating function $$[z^M]\ \prod_{k=0}^N (1-q^{k^2}z)^{-1}.$$